# $(this).click() internet explorer issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

this code/markup in conjunction with a php script renders a multiple select input populated with options set to
files via a php script. The goal is when a user clicks on an option, the text file is read and output to a div $("#txtbx").
This works as planned in mozilla firefox, however ie9 does nothing, no error no output.
As you can see by the comments i've located the ofending piece of code. It is not an .each() issue as I first thought, nor is it a selector issue (i've referenced it directly by class: see the comment). Neither is it $(this) i've also tested that... it seems to be the event being attached to $(this) or the event itself. Where the ouput goes is irrelevant because it doesn't make it past $(this).click(f). Any idea what is happening here?

```
<div id="txtbx">
</div>

<select id="REFselect" size="1">
<option class="REFoptions" value="./TXT/css.txt">css.txt</option>
<option class="REFoptions" value="./TXT/dns.txt">dns.txt</option>
</select>

$("#REFselect option").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert("test")
        /*
        $("#txtbx").load($(this).val(),function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            $(this).html("<pre>"+responseTxt+"</pre>");
            if(statusTxt=="success")
              alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            if(statusTxt=="error")
              alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

        });
        */
    });
});
```

This is the working code, I'm new to the site so I want to thank everyone for their answers they were very good. I don't know how to award proper credit, I'm researching that.
Also I would love to know why the old code worked in FF and not IE.

```
$("#REFselect").change(function(){
        var select = $(this).val();

        $("#txtbx").load(select,function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
            $(this).html("<pre>"+responseTxt+"</pre>");
            if(statusTxt=="success")
              alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            if(statusTxt=="error")
              alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);  
        });
});
```

Comment: I believe that your `this` inside the `load` callback will no longer be the clicked element, you need to store it in a variable and use the variable in the `load` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tying your `.click` handler to the `<option>` elements (which do not have a `click` event to handle).

Try setting it to the `.change` event of the `<select>` element.

```
$("#REFselect").change(function (e) {
    alert("test")
    $("#txtbx").load($(this).val(), function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
        $(this).html("<pre>" + responseTxt + "</pre>");
        if (statusTxt == "success") {
            alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        }
        if (statusTxt == "error") {
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: also add description why it was working on mozilla and why not on IE ?

Comment: @AspiringAqib: I would, but I don't understand why it would have worked in FF (save for event bubbling, but the handler wasn't bound to the select, so... I dunno).

Comment: I'll happily +1 an answer that adequately explains why the OP's code worked in FF. :)

Comment: I don't know how to close the question, post the working code, award credit, etc... +1 an answer? I'd love to know why code worked in FF

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#REFselect").on("change", function() {
   $("#txtbx").load($(this).val(),function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
        $(this).html("<pre>"+responseTxt+"</pre>");
        if(statusTxt=="success")
          alert("External content loaded successfully!");
        if(statusTxt=="error")
          alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

    });
});
```

You can use `.on()` to bind event on all options of select tag! and also change event as bfavaretto suggested.

Comment: Yes, now it's different. I'm suggesting a different approach on my answer, though, since I'm not sure how clicks on option elements (and `.val()` on option elements) is handled cross-browser.

Comment: Just FIY: using `$('selector').click(callback)` is a shortcut to `$('selector').on('click', callback)`. It's not deprecated. What has been deprecated is `.live`, which should be replaced with a different form of `.on` (`$('ancestor').on('click', 'selector', callback)`. The same is true for `change` and all other events.

Comment: jbaby hinted on it, pete spelled it out, apparently in ie9 (as it worked on mozilla) there is no click event on option. Also, I took bfavareto's suggestion to put $(this).val() in variable and pass it to load() (I'm assuming IE9 considers $(this) to point to $("#txtbx") now. Still confused as to why mozilla would see that differently. I'm new to this forum, how do I post the working code and award credit?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the inner `$(this)` (supposedly an `<option>` element). Try to get the value directly form the `<select>`, using the `change` event:

```
$("#REFselect").change(function(){
     alert("test");
     $("#txtbx").load($(this).val(),function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
         $(this).html("<pre>"+responseTxt+"</pre>");
         if(statusTxt=="success")
             alert("External content loaded successfully!");
         if(statusTxt=="error")
             alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);

     });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can bind events to `option` elements.  Also, the `each` is not needed here as `.change` will bind to all elements in the set anyway.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I answered too fast and didn't pay much attention to my copy/paste. The intention was precisely to avoid targeting option elements directly. Fixed now.